# How to get an input value without using any ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code from which I want to get value. I don't have any IDs, so please help me. How I can get the values by using jQuery and JavaScript?

```
<p>Nama*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
        <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </span> 
</p>
<p>Email*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
        <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </span> 
</p>
<p>Pertanyaan/Cerita*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
        <textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
    </span> 
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" />
</p>
```

Comment: `$('input[name="your-name"]')`

Answer (score 5):

Apply with `form` tag .And get via `serialize()` function .Its show's the all value of the input fields

**Older method**

```js
$(document).on('click' ,'input[type=submit]' ,function () {
  
  console.log($('form').serialize());
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form><!---its help full to get all value.--->
<p>Nama*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
    <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p>Email*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
    <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p>Pertanyaan/Cerita*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
    <textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
  </form>
```

**Updated another method**

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() //prevent refresh
  console.log($(this).serialize());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <!---its help full to get all value.--->
  <p>Nama*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
    <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
  <p>Email*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
    <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
  <p>Pertanyaan/Cerita*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
    <textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What an epic little feature of jQuery that is. With this, my fear of forms, post, get and all that have mostly vanished.

Comment: Thank you soo much

Comment: Thank you. It's basically a legend answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get element by its name attribute for that [use an attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
var name = $('[name="your-name"]').val(),
    email = $('[name="your-email"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can select the field by its `name`.

`$('[name="your-name"]').val() //=> "Jerry"`

Comment: Thanks @doctoroange , I need your help once again, I'm using this piece of code but its not working, can you please let me know why its not working. Thank you so much

Comment: $(".wpcf7-form").submit(function(e) {
    analytics.track("Response", {
    email: $('[name="your-email"]').val(),
    gospel_video_url: gospelURL,
    name: $('[name="your-name"]').val(),  
    response_text: $('[name="your-message"]').val(),
    site_type_id: siteTypeId 
    });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
var name = $(".your-name").val();
var email = $(".your-email").val();
var message = $(".your-message").val();
```